# Inserting .format() text as a variable into selenium WebDriverWait

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, format

I'm trying to select an xpath element with selenium using the .format() to select the window based on external variables.

```
WebDriverWait({}, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, var))).click().format('driver' + str(text_response_count.number + 2))
```

However, I keep getting the error

```
dict object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

If I put parenthesis around the {} I get

```
str object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

which seems to suggest that it is not recognizing the {} as being part of the .format().

I've tried

```
WebDriverWait({}, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, var))).format('driver' + str(text_response_count.number + 2)).click()
```

and

```
WebDriverWait({}, 10).format('driver' + str(text_response_count.number + 2)).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, var))).click()
```

But nothing works.
I'm assuming all of the dot statements in between are disconnecting the WebDriverWait variables from the .format() statement.

How does one make this function properly?

Edit:
I also tried

```
driver_var = '{}'
WebDriverWait(driver_var.format('driver' + str(text_response_count.number + 2)), 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, var))).click()
```

and got

```
str object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

I don't get it. that should have worked.

Comment: The first argument of `WebDriverWait` is an instance of WebDriver, where as `{}` and `format()` are for string manupulation. I doubt if you can work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `format('driver' + str(text_response_count.number + 2)`, try the following syntax:

`f"driver + {str(text_response_count.number + 2)}"`